# Conda: I installed `conda-build` 3.19.2 but version listed is 3.18.11

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

This is kinda weird--I installed the latest version 3.19.2 of `conda-build` in an environment, but I cannot seem to access that latest version. The environment keeps referencing version 3.18.11.

I want to use `conda-build` version 3.19.2 and I installed it in my environment. But for some reason I cannot seem to access it.

Here is a way to recreate the issue. Note that I am using `conda-forge` so that is setup in my `.condarc`.

1. create a new anaconda environment using conda version 4.8.3.

   ```
    conda create -c conda-forge -n pkg-builder conda-build
   ```
2. When I check the `conda-build` version it indicates 3.19.2

   ```
    conda list conda-build

    Name                    Version                   Build  Channel \
    conda-build               3.19.2           py38h32f6830_2    conda-forge
   ```
3. When I try and use `conda-build` it reads an older version

   ```
    conda build --version

    >>> 3.18.11
   ```
4. Conda info reads shows the wrong version too--even though the higher level is installed.

   ```
    conda info

     active environment : pkg-builder
     active env location : /../anaconda3/envs/pkg-builder
     shell level : 3
     user config file : /../.condarc
     populated config files : /../.condarc
     conda version : 4.8.3
     conda-build version : 3.18.11   <--------THIS IS THE WRONG VERSION - SHOULD BE 3.19.2
     python version : 3.8.3.final.0
     virtual packages : __cuda=10.0
                          __glibc=2.27
     base environment : /../anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
     package cache : /../anaconda3/pkgs
                          /../.conda/pkgs
     envs directories : /../anaconda3/envs
                          /../.conda/envs
     platform : linux-64
     user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.3 Linux/4.15.0-112-generic  
                  ubuntu/18.04.4 glibc/2.27
                  UID:GID : 1000:1000
                  netrc file : /../.netrc
                  offline mode : False
   ```

How can I access the correct version of `conda-build`?

Comment: Conda-build must be installed in the `base` environment. It doesn't work (as you see here) when installed in another environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find a reference for this, so it's just based on several years of experience with `conda-build` :-)